# Can someone give a clear cut understanding of the usage of pi in trigonometric equations?

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry, pi, unit-of-measure

Through out my studies, I had been through a lot of trigonometry and differential equations with trigonometry.
Whenever 'pi' appears inside the sin/cos/tan..etc, I assumed it to be 180, and when it appeared outside due to integration or something else, I assumed it to be the irrational number-3.14, sometimes, both at a time.
I read a lot about radians and degrees. But Most math problems don't specify if it's radians or degrees.
Is it implied that whenever pi appears inside the trigonometric functions it is in degrees and outside in radians? or the other way round? Sorry I'm totally confused. I just wanna have some clarity.
Also, calculators seem to take the same 'pi' value inside and outside which is causing ridiculous errors. like sin 180 coming out as sin 22/7*.
Please help.

Please give an example: say this:
So, if there is an integral which, say x*sin(x), integrated over 0 and pi/5., After the integration is over, how do you apply the limits? Do you use pi=180 inside the -cos and the irrational just number on the plain old x?

Comment: Have you read something like https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/radians.html and https://betterexplained.com/articles/intuitive-guide-to-angles-degrees-and-radians/?

Comment: @Moo, I read that. It clearly says it is different units. But please see the question again, I added an example. Please answer that too.

Comment: "Pi=180" in the same sense as "1=1.609". 1 mile is 1.609 km, and similarly pi radians (3.14... radians) is 180 degrees. 3.14... radians does equal 180°, and sin(pi) = sin(180°), but that does not mean that pi is 180. I think the source of your confusion is that radians and degrees are not normally treated like units (leaving off the ° is fairly common, and using radians implicitly is almost the rule), however they do require a conversion factor (180 degrees / pi radians) to switch between.

Comment: As far as your calculator, my guess would be it's trying (and perhaps failing) to guess whether you mean radians or degrees. sin(180˚)=sin(pi)=0. sin(22/7)~0 (not exactly since it's only an approximation of pi). sin(22/7°)~0.05 - but this is on the opposite side of the unit circle from sin(pi) (cos here is almost +1 instead of -1); it's very close to sin(3) which is very close to sin(0)=0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion originates from misunderstanding radians and degrees.

$\pi$ is a number. It happens that the circumference of a circle is always $2\pi$ times the radius of the circle. So, in radians, an angle of $\pi$ does correspond to an angle of $180$ degrees.

However, $\pi \neq 180.$ When you see $\pi$ appearing in an integral, it's probably appearing as an area--$\pi$ is the area of the unit circle.

We may define $1^{\circ} = \pi/180$ to define degrees. But that just means 1 degree equals $\pi/180,$ not that $1 = \pi/180.$

Just like $100\text{cm} = 1\text{m}$ doesn't mean $100=1.$ There are different units.

Comment: Very good.  Emphasis on *$ \pi $ is just a number*.

Comment: So, if there is an integral which, say  x*sin(x), integrated over 0 and pi/2., After the integration is over, how do you apply the limits? Do you use pi=180 inside the -cos and the irrational just number on the plain old x?

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta In calculus, we almost always work with radians. Also, $\pi \neq 180$. As Michael rightly notes, $\pi \text{ rad} = 180^{\text{o}}$. So I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Joe, it's a simple question. When you integrate x*sin(x) over the limit 0 and pi/2, what is the absolute final value in numbers?

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta $1$.

Comment: @Joe, guess what. My calculator is spitting out everything except one. That's the problem. Okay. Lets say the limits ar 0 to pi/5. How would that evolve?

Comment: @Joe, I edited the above reply. Please see again. Thanks.

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta Your calculator is likely finding the value of $\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\sin^\text{o}(x) x \, dx$ rather than $\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\sin^\text{r}(x) x \, dx$. $\sin^\text{o}$ and $\sin^\text{r}$ are different functions.

Comment: Sorry for eating up your time. Final question. When I check the answer for the same question but with limits 0 to pi/5, I saw that the final expression was sin(pi/5)-[(pi*cos(pi/5)/5)]. After reverse engineering the value of pi which is outside the cos, I @Joe got it as 3.14. Which is correct as per the definition. But when applied Inside the cos, it has become 180. As you've said. So it simply means, in mathematics, we always convert the pi-the number into radians when used inside the trignomentric function? right.

Comment: @Joe, This simply means that Casio calculators don't convert the pi into radians when used inside the trignomentric functions causing this error. Okay. Yup. Got the clarity. Thanks So much.

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta Yes, unfortunately, calculators don't use common sense. When you input $\sin \pi$, they interpret it as $\pi^{\text{o}}$, even though a human would understand from context that you mean $\pi \text{ rad}$.

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta The trouble occurs because there are two functions that use the representation $\sin$. The first one, $\sin^\text{o}(x)$ is the $y$-coordinate when you go $x$ degrees anticlockwise around a unit circle, starting from the point $(0,1)$. $\sin^\text{r}(x)$ is exactly the same, *except* that you are going $x$ radians around the circle.

Comment: @Joe Yeah. I got it. Thanks. Always make pi --> 180 when taking into the trignomentric functions. -->Unless it is a complex/plot representation where it could be a co-ordinate. But that shall be specified by the question. Yup.

Comment: @Joe, can you please make this into an answer. That'll be helpful to all.